# Do I need to put --mount-type=cache on every RUN or just the first?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

Given I have a multistage Docker file for a gradle build with a dependencies layer a common build layer and layers for multiple executables.

If I do

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew dependencies
```

in the dependencies layer, do I need to also do

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew :com.foo.common:build
```

and

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle ./gradlew  com.foo.bar:build
```

in the other layers or is just the first

```
--mount=type=cache,target=/root/.gradle
```

enough?

Every example I've found only has 1 RUN command, so I can't figure this out just from documentation

Comment: Yes, you need to repeat the argument for each layer you want a cache to be available in.